# Adding empty groups to a group by clause (getting all 24 hours of the day represented)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a the below query

```
 SELECT

    datepart(hh,[Start Time]) as [Hour]

    ,SUM(
    CASE ...
    END) as [Calls Answered]

From [table]

group by datepart(hh,[Start Time])
```

which I use to generate this chart of calls per hour

[image: chart]

As you can see not every hour of the day has data in it so SSMS doesn't show these hours. Is there a straightforward way in SQL of getting the missing hours included with 0s for the [Calls Answered] field? I'm on SQL server 2016 fwiw.

Comment: Outer join with a temporary table storing the values 1 to 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE (or other method) to generate 24 hours:

```
with hours as (
      select 0 as h
      union all
      select h + 1
      from hours
      where h + 1 < 24
    )
select hours.h as [Hour],
       sum(case . . . else 0 end) as [Calls Answered]
from hours left join
     [table] t
     on hours.h = datepart(hour, [Start Time])
group by hours.h
order by hours.h;
```

The `else 0` is one way to (probably) ensure that `sum()` returns `0` instead of `NULL`.  If you already have an `else`, you need to be careful, because some hours might not have any matches in your table.

Comment: For whatever reason I can't get this to work https://imgur.com/daFkLcc can anyone see what I'm doing wrong from this picture?

Comment: @tomdemaine . . . The conditions in the `WHERE` clause on the second table should be in the `ON` clause.